# C++11 - std::function, templates and function objects, weird issues

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, anonymous-function

I'm playing with some code and I am a little puzzled about some stuff. Here's a simplified example:

I have `Nodes` that perform arithmetical operations (addition, subtraction, etc). I have a container with the different operations that are available in my program. Here's an example:

```
typedef std::binary_function<double, std::vector<double>&, std::vector<Node*>& > my_binary_function;
auto const & product = [](double v, Node* n){ return v * n->GetEvaluation(); };
struct addition : public my_binary_function {
double
    operator()(std::vector<double>& weights, std::vector<Node*>& subtrees) {
        return std::inner_product(weights.begin(), weights.end(), 
        subtrees.begin(), 0, std::plus<double>(), product);
    }
};
```

Now, at this point there are two choices:

1) use a function type:

```
typedef double (*my_function)(std::vector<double>&, std::vector<Node*>&);
```

Then use the following templated function to convert the functors:

```
template<typename F> typename F::result_type
func(typename F::first_argument_type arg1, typename F::second_argument_type arg2) {
    return F()(arg1, arg2);
}
```

2) use a function wrapper type, namely `std::function`, so that I have

```
typedef std::function<double (std::vector<double>&, std::vector<Node*>&)> my_function;
```

It all boils down to something like this:

```
LoadDefaultFunctions() {
    int minArity = 2;
    int maxArity = 2;
    function_set_.AddFunction("Add", func<addition> , minArity, maxArity, 1.0); // case 1
OR
    function_set_.AddFunction("Add", addition(), minArity, maxArity, 1.0); // case 2
```

And now the problems:

a) If I use Method 1, I get this compilation error:

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 
'std::binary_function<double, std::vector<double>&, 
std::vector<Node*>&>::result_type {aka std::vector<Node*>&}' 
from an rvalue of type 'double'
```

The error goes away if I change the template (notice how the arguments don't really make sense now):

```
template <typename F> typename F::first_argument_type
func1(typename F::second_argument_type arg1, typename F::result_type arg2) {
    return F()(arg1, arg2); 
}
```

I find it very strange, because for other types such as `binary_op<double, double, double>`, the first form works fine. So, what's happening?

b) 1) is faster than 2) (by a small margin). I'm thinking I'm probably missing some neat trick of passing the functor by reference or in some way that would enable `std::function` to wrap it more efficiently. Any ideas?

c) If I use the typedef from 2) but additionally I still use `func` to produce a function out of the functor, and let `std::function` deal with it, it's still faster than 2). That is:

```
`my_function = func<addition>` is faster than `my_function = addition()`
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand the mechanics behind all of this.

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `std::result_of` to obtain the result type of *any* callable entity generically.

Comment: Your usage of `std::binary_function` is a bit off (a matter of the order of parameters, notice how `result_type` isn't `double` in the message). Rather than fix that though, can you simply not use it? It's been deprecated in favor of `std::result_of` (as KerrekSB points out), which only has to be used by clients of `addition`, and not in the implementation of `addition` itself.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that part, I didn't know binary_function was deprecated, and I don't usually mix the template parameters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> b) 1) is faster than 2) (by a small margin). I'm thinking I'm probably missing some neat trick of passing the functor by reference or in some way that would enable std::function to wrap it more efficiently. Any ideas?

Yes, I would expect 1 to be faster than 2. `std::function` performs type-erasure (the exact type of the stored *callable* is not present in the enclosing `std::function` type) which requires the use of a virtual function call. On the other hand, when you use a template, the exact type is known, and the compiler has greater chances of inlining the calls, making it a no-cost solution. This is not related to how you pass the functor.

**The error**

The order of the template arguments is incorrect:

```
typedef std::binary_function<double,                 // arg1
                             std::vector<double>&,   // arg2
                             std::vector<Node*>&     // return type
                            > my_binary_function;

struct addition : public my_binary_function {
    double                                           // return type
    operator()( std::vector<double>& weights,        // arg1 
                std::vector<Node*>& subtrees)        // arg2
    { ...
```

That is, inheritance from `binary_function` is adding some typedefs to your class, but those are not the correct typedefs. Then when you use the typedefs in the next template, the types don't match. The template is expecting that your `operator()` will return a `std::vector<Node*>&`, and that is the return type of `func`, but when you call the functor what you get is a `double` which leads to the error:

> invalid initialization of ... `std::vector<Node*>&` from `double`

Comment: std::function doesn't technically require a virtual call, the GCC implementation and (at least last time I looked at it) boost implementation store a pointer to a function template which is instantiated with the callable type, before it's erased.  There's still an indirection, but not necessarily a virtual function call.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Well... in boost 1.49 it is not a `virtual` function call, it is a call dispatched through a member of `function_base` called `vtable`... The library implements it's own virtual dispatch, but at any rate, to be able to perform type erasure (and maintain state) you need *virtual dispatch* of shorts.